# Difference between mandatory and obligatory

Tags: differences

I wish to know the difference between these words. I only know few examples of them being used in speech for now: Mandatory circumcision and Obligatory military service. In my native language, we use same word in both cases so I can't seem to be able to tell the diffrence.

Comment: [M-W Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/compulsory-mandatory-and-obligatory) has a good article on this. However, the collocations it gives hardly apply in the UK, where the terms are largely interchangeable. 'Compulsory' is more common in many contexts in the UK.

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Are the words “mandatory,” “obligatory,” and “compulsory” interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/are-the-words-mandatory-obligatory-and-compulsory-interchangeable)