# Why is it called Compulsory education not Mandatory education or Obligation education?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

I know it is called [Compulsory education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_education)

> Compulsory education refers to a period of education that is required
> of all people and is imposed by the government.
>
> Compulsory school attendance or compulsory schooling means that
> parents are obliged to send their children to a certain school.

Since parents are **obliged** to send their children to a certain school, why not call it  **Obligation education** or **Mandatory education** but Compulsory education?

BTW, I notice the difference between [Obliged and Obligated](https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-obliged-and-obligated/) or the question asked here [Are the words "mandatory," "obligatory," and "compulsory" interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/are-the-words-mandatory-obligatory-and-compulsory-interchangeable) but they didn't answer the question.

Comment: They put the possible words on a dart board and throw darts to pick one.

Comment: The adjective is obligatory.

Comment: _Compulsory education_ is the idiomatic phrase listed in dictionaries. Asking why it is idiomatic might not get you anywhere. It's just like that.

Comment: @fev Well that could be an answer.

Comment: English idioms make as much sense as Chinese two-character words. I.e, sporadically but not reliably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your assertion that it is not also called "mandatory education" lacks foundation. In fact, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mandatory%20education&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmandatory%20education%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmandatory%20education%3B%2Cc0) provides foundation for the antithesis:

[image]

Here is a link to some of the published references that were used in creating the above Google Ngram and that provide citations wherein "mandatory education" is used in such a manner:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mandatory%20education%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2015,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

As for "obligation education," it is never properly called that in English because "obligation" is a noun and so isn't used as an adjective to modify "education" in lieu of an adjectival form.

Comment: Your image of the Ngram is positively misleading. You must include the comparators: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mandatory+education%2Cobligatory+education%2Ccompulsory+education&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmandatory%20education%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobligatory%20education%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompulsory%20education%3B%2Cc0 **Obligatory** and **Mandatory** are a vanishingly small percentage of the accepted collocation.

Comment: The only thing that is misleading is your comment since my answer and the Ngram and Ngram results that prove it simply document the established usage of "mandatory." There's no "must" for me to include comparators because I'm not drawing any comparisons, not suggesting any comparisons, not hinting at any comparisons. You're the one doing that, not me. Now, if my answer were to draw, hint, or suggest "mandatory" were ***better*** than another term, like "compulsory" or "obligatory," or ***more often used***, *only then must I* or even *would I* include comparators. Your downvote is unwarranted.